# Macros and Rust compiler plugin conflicts

Tags: macros, rust

I want to develop a [syntax extension](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/compiler-plugins.html#syntax-extensions) to annotate Rust code; I hope to define a global attribute like `#![test]`.

My code runs well with a single function declared with `#[check]`, but when it comes to applying it to all the items declared with `#![check]`, it prompts with errors resulting from several macros:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#![plugin(myplugin)]
#![check]

struct AA {
    x: i32,
}

macro_rules! hello_AA {
    () => ( AA {x: 3});
}  

fn main() {
    let x = hello_AA!();
    println!("x.x = {}",x.x);
}
```

The code failed with errors below:

```
error: cannot find macro `hello_AA!` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:21:13
   |
21 |     let x = hello_AA!();
   |             ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: have you added the `#[macro_use]` on the module/import?
```

It seems the macros are not expanded properly when the plugin runs. The error is related to the codes in myplugin, specially the code below:

```
fn fold_expr(&mut self, e: P<Expr>) -> P<Expr> {
    //ok with the original
    //e.map(|e| fold::noop_fold_expr(e, self))

    match e.unwrap() {
        //This expression cause error
        e@Expr {node: ExprKind::Mac(_), ..} => {
            let expanded = self.cx.expander().fold_expr(P(e));
            self.fold_expr(expanded)
        }
        e => P(fold::noop_fold_expr(e,self)),
    }
}
```

An code illustrating this:
`git clone git@github.com:qorost/rust_macro_plugin.git`

Comment: Can you show your `myplugin` code as a [mcve]?

Comment: @kennytm  git@github.com:qorost/rust_macro_plugin.git
I just uploaded the example code. Thanks for your attention.